# How to access [(ngModel)] from another component?

Tags: angular, ngmodel, ngx-quill

I have a common component which holds ngx-quill component. Which I want to call in several other components for getting editor instead of input field. I was successful in making that work. But I am using ngModels to do two way data binding, which can not be used on Div. How can I access them in my common component.

So this is my common component :

common_component.html

```
<quill-editor>
</quill-editor>
```

Common_component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'underscore';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-quill-editor',
    templateUrl: './common_component.html'
})

export class CommanQuillComponent {

    constructor(
    ) {}

}
```

This is where I am calling it :

main_component.html

```html
<div>
    <app-quill-editor
        id="float-input"
        placeholder=" "
        name="myRange"
        step="1"
        [(ngModel)]="myVar"
    ></app-quill-editor>
</div>
```

main_component.ts holds nothing but variable declaration.

Now problem here is ngModel can not be used on div(it will throw error), html considers  as div tag, then calls  inside it, I want to have that ngModel on , I can not put it manually as this is going to be used as common component.

Please help me understand how can I achieve this data binding ?

Thank you for support and let me know if more understandable code should be added to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your looking for is `ControlValueAccessor` for implementing custom form control so that two-way data binding can work on custom component.

Let's say you binded `value` variable on the `quill-editor`:

```js
<quill-editor [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></quill-editor>
```

```js
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CommanQuillComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CommanQuillComponent implements ControlValueAccessor() {
   value: string = '';

   ...
   // Add other properties as Input
   @Input()
   placeholder: string;

   ...

   propagateChange = (_: any) => {};
   registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }
  
  writeValue(value: string) {
     this.value = value; // <- you receive the value which is binded to this component here
  }

  onChange(event: string) {
     this.value = event;
     this.propagateChange(event); // <- you export the value so the binded variable is updated
  }
}
```

Now you can use two-way data binding on that `CommanQuillComponent`:

```html
<div>
    <app-quill-editor
        id="float-input"
        placeholder=" "
        name="myRange"
        step="1"
        [(ngModel)]="myVar"
    ></app-quill-editor>
</div>
```

There are many articles online that you can read to get more details:

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

https://javascript-conference.com/blog/angular-reactive-forms-building-custom-form-controls/

https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/angular-build-custom-form-control/